# Java gettext + adding a number

Tags: java, numbers, addition, settext

i need some help to gettext an integer and then after i get the integer from what the user added, i need to add 10 to it thanks for help the code is below;\

```
private void btnCalculateMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{                                          
    Integer memoryAdd1, total, radBlue1, radWhite1, radBlack1, microsoftYes1, 
        caseA1, batteryA1, webcamA1, windows20001, windowsVista1;

    radBlack1 = 0;
    radWhite1 = 0;
    radBlue1 = 0;
    microsoftYes1 = 0;
    caseA1 = 0;
    batteryA1 = 0;
    webcamA1 = 0;
    windows20001 = 0;
    windowsVista1 = 0;
    memoryAdd1 = 0;

    if (radBlack.isSelected()) { radBlack1 = radBlack1 + 5; };

    if (radWhite.isSelected()) { radWhite1 = radWhite1 + 5; };

    if (radBlue.isSelected()) { radWhite1 = radWhite1 + 10; };

    memoryAdd.getText(Integer.toString( memoryAdd1 = memoryAdd1+10));

    if (microsoftYes.isSelected()) { microsoftYes1 = microsoftYes1 + 100; };

    if (caseA.isSelected()) { caseA1 = caseA1 + 50; };

    if (batteryA.isSelected()) { batteryA1 = batteryA1 + 30; };

    if (webcamA.isSelected()) { webcamA1 = webcamA1 + 25; };

    if (windows2000.isSelected()) { windows20001 = windows20001 + 300; };

    if (windowsVista.isSelected()) { windowsVista1 = windowsVista1 + 300; };

    total = radBlack1 + radWhite1 + radBlue1 + microsoftYes1 + caseA1 + 
        batteryA1 + webcamA1 + windows20001 + windowsVista1;

    beforeTax.setText(Integer.toString(total));
```

}

Comment: What error are you getting when you do that?

Comment: Hello thanks for replaying. I replaced the : memoryAdd.getText(Integer.toString( memoryAdd1 = memoryAdd1+10)); line with : memoryAdd2 = memoryAdd.getText();
    
    memoryAdd3 = memoryAdd2 * 10; but im still getting an error

Comment: Can you explain what type of error you had on the first attempt? You need to be specific.

Comment: im getting anothe error bad operand types for binary operator '*' first type: java.lang.String , second type: int

Comment: Well I think the problem is that your doing math when your value already converted to a string. You should probably add 10 before you convert

Answer (score 2):

It looks like casting issue only..

```
    MemoryAdd1+=10 
    String str = Integer.toString( memoryAdd1)
    memoryAdd.getText(str);
```

by the way what is your memoryAdd? it's AWT textbox? are you trying to setvalue in it?

Comment: thanks for all the peoples help ... i got it using the following code: memoryAdd2 = Double.parseDouble(memoryAdd.getText()); memoryAdd1 = memoryAdd2 + 10;

Comment: i had to change the variables from integer to a double for everything which seemed to work . Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that once the value is inside the convert function you can't do math with it anymore because it is now a string.

Try this instead

```
MemoryAdd1+=10

memoryAdd.getText(Integer.toString( memoryAdd1));
```

Comment: Yeah .. im still getting that error even when i do the math first'

Comment: Then I think it must be the gettext function thats the culprit. Let me investigate